# How to add a field to a class in ByteBuddy and set / get that value in a method interceptor

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I am using byte-buddy to build an ORM on top of Ignite, we need to add a field to a class and then access it in a method interceptor..

So here's an example where I add a field to a class

```
final ByteBuddy buddy = new ByteBuddy();

final Class<? extends TestDataEnh> clz =  buddy.subclass(TestDataEnh.class)
        .defineField("stringVal",String.class)
        .method(named("setFieldVal")).intercept(
            MethodDelegation.to(new SetterInterceptor())
    )
    .make()
    .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
    .getLoaded();

final TestDataEnh enh = clz.newInstance();

enh.getFieldVal();
enh.setFieldVal();

System.out.println(enh.getClass().getName());
```

And the Interceptor is like this

```
public class SetterInterceptor {
    @RuntimeType
    public  Object intercept() {
        System.out.println("Invoked method with: ");
        return null;
    }
}
```

So how do I get the value of the new field into the interceptor so I can change it's value? (stringVal)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FieldProxy`](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.1.0/net/bytebuddy/implementation/bind/annotation/FieldProxy.html) to access a field by its name. You need to install a `FieldProxy.Binder` and register it on the `MethodDdelegation` before you can use it as it requires a custom type for type-safe instrumentation. The *javadoc* explains how this can be done. Alternatively, you can use reflection on an instance by using `@This`. The JVM is quite efficient in optimizing the use of reflection.

An example would be:

```
interface FieldGetter {
  Object getValue();
}

interface FieldSetter {
  void setValue(Object value);
}

public class SetterInterceptor {
  @RuntimeType
  public  Object intercept(@FieldProxy("stringVal") FieldGetter accessor) {
    Object value = accessor.getValue();
    System.out.println("Invoked method with: " + value);
    return value;
  }
}
```

For bean properties, the `FieldProxy` annotation does not require an explicit name but discovers the name from the name of the intercepted getter or setter.

The installation can be done as follows:

```
MethodDelegation.to(SetterInterceptor.class)
                .appendParameterBinder(FieldProxy.Binder.install(FieldGetter.class, 
                                                                 FieldSetter.class));
```

Comment: Ok in my case we don't know what the name of the field will be until Runtime, but I think you've given me enough to work on ..

We are adding a hidden field to store some relational information in the class before serializing it to the data store..

Comment: Just for future reference of this Stack Overflow.. How would I access a field if I don't know the name of the field until runtime?

I'm looking at
     FieldProxy.Binder.install(TypeDescription.AbstractBase.OfSimpleType

To put the field name in, but I get lost there.

Comment: Do the field names follow the Java bean convention? The simply leave the field empty. Otherwise, you can really just use reflection on a `@This` object. As long as you cache the `Field` instances, this has no relevance to performance. Access of reflection is achieved by reading directly from the heap using `sun.misc.Unsafe`. No byte code generation can compete with this level of performance.